# String to date and to time

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime

Hello i'm having trouble with converting string to date, and date to string with time only.
Result is null.

Here is what i am doing:

I have a dictionary, with time in it:

```
@"Time" : @"2014-07-17T10:38:00+03:00"
```

I do this:

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormat2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
NSDate *date = [timeFormat2 dateFromString:[JSON valueForKey:@"Time"]];
```

And then this:

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"%@",[timeFormat stringFromDate:date]);
cell.iboTimeLabel.text = [timeFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

And the value is null.

**Where is my mistake?**

Comment: Remove all the single quotes from the TimeString and try.

Comment: Could you please try this: [timeFormat2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"];? Currently running Windows here...

Comment: Akaino, no without quotes doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from the Time string and try. Use the following date formatter.

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormat2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *date = [timeFormat2 dateFromString:@"2014-07-17T10:38:00+03:00"];
```

Comment: Thought about the same^^ You were slightly faster :P

Answer (score 3):

You are setting Format of your string date is wrong check with Bellow code:

```
  NSString *str=@"2014-07-17T10:38:00+03:00";

    NSDateFormatter *timeFormat2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormat2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
    NSDate *date = [timeFormat2 dateFromString:str];


    [timeFormat2 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

    NSString *final = [timeFormat2 stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@",final);
```

Comment: Thanks. But Suresh was the first with correct answer. I will up vote yours.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this format

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormat2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [timeFormat2 dateFromString:@"2014-07-17T10:38:00+03:00"];


NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"%@",[timeFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

It's working. i hope this is working for you.

Comment: Thanks. But Suresh was the first with correct answer. I will up vote yours.

Comment: You didn't upvote the question, despite it being clear enough for you to answer.  One good turn deserves another...

Answer (score 1):

Set the dateformat to `[timeFormat2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];` should do the trick also i suggest [reading this document](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns) next time you are dealing with such issues.